# Expresión regular para hacer replace HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, regex

Buen día estoy tratando de generar una expresión regular para darle un tratamiento de cadena a un string, lo que quiero es poner `:` después de cada 2 numeros, se que lo podría hacer con un `substring` pero quisiera hacerlo con la expresión regular.

```js
var str = "013012";

console.log(str.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2}))/g, ":"));
console.log('String esperado 01:30:12')
// String Obtenido 0:1:3:0:12
// String esperado 01:30:12
```

Espero me puedan ayudar

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la siguiente función:

```js
function insert(val) {
var str = val.replace(/(\S{2})/g,"$1:");
str = str.replace(/:$/,""); //Elimina la última inserción
return str
}

console.log(insert('013012'));
console.log(insert('034311'));
```

Agregué una expresión regular para agregar `:` cada 2 caracteres y otra expresión donde se elimina el que encuentra al final de la cadena.

Espero sea de tu ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Funciono Muy bien Gracias.

Comment: Genial, de nada compañero, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

esto te puede servir:

```js
var str = "013012";

//Si conoces el número de dígitos puedes usar este método
console.log(str.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, "$1:$2:$3")); 
//Si no conoces el número de dígitos puedes usar este método(Referencia a la respuesta de Blas David)
console.log(str.replace(/(\d{2})/g, "$1:").replace(/:$/,""));
//
console.log('String esperado 01:30:12')
```

En el primer método: Al usar el símbolo de dólar ($) representa el bloque que coincide con la expresión que está entre paréntesis. Por eso separé en 3 grupos $1:$2:$3 para que tengas el formato deseado.

En el segundo método: Si no sabemos la cantidad de dígitos. podemos reemplazar cada 2 dígitos y agregarle los dos puntos ":" luego lo recuperamos con el símbolo de dolar ($) y como es el único (primer) valor ponemos el número 1. Es porque eso que se ve $1. Porque al encontrar 2 dígitos concatenará los 2 puntos. Finalmente como te sobrarían 2 puntos  al final, hacemos un reenplazo que elimine la última coincidencia. Es por eso que ves el símbolo del dolar ($) sin un número al lado. Saludos!